# assumption such that the explicit formula of heat equation holds

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

In Evans PDE book, Section 2.3, Theorem 2. It says that if $f\in C^2_1(\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty))$ and $f$ has compact support, then 
$$
u(x, t)=\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \Phi(x-y, t-s) f(y, s) d y d s
$$
is the solution of $u_t-\Delta u=f$. Here $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution.

My question is, can we relax the assumption on $f$?

For example,if $f$ is discontinuous like $f=0$ on $x<0$ and $f=1$ on $x>0$, does this formula still hold?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Compact support just makes the proof easier and it ensures the solution will exist for all $t$. Another condition often seen is bounded and continuous. You can further relax bounded by some growth condition on $f$ (but then the solution might break down at some $t$). And finally you can also relax continuity at some points (intuitively since a function with a finite number of jump discontinuites is well approximated by continuous functions). For your concrete example see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644731/heat-equation-step-function-initial-condition